# CUPS printer is getting deleted spontaneously

Tags: linux-mint, cups, delete

I have a Brother HL2240 printer attached to a Linux Mint machine, using KDE, and shared to my other home's computers. However, it gets removed from CUPS spontaneously. Despite that everytime I add the printer back, it gets removed after a while. Looking into the CUPS log I found many entries like:

```
localhost - - [26/Mar/2019:00:32:30 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 172 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - aizquier [26/Mar/2019:00:32:30 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 172 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
```

Who or what is accessing CUPS asking it to delete the printer in my behalf? Perhaps do I have a security issue? or it is a cron job?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in cups on Ubuntu that sounds the same.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1731417